# How do I delete duplicates based on multiple fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I want to delete duplicates based on my time/date column (1st column) but I want to keep the ones that have a 1 in the 2nd column. Essentially, I want to delete all rows that are a duplicate of 1st column AND are "2" in the 2nd column. How do I do this in ArcGIS?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify which rows you want deleted (why `WHERE dup_type = 2` couldn't be used as a simple WHERE constraint)

Comment: Try dissolving on all the columns in your table. Are you wanting to group by minute or by seconds?

Comment: @Vince  I have updated the question to try make it more clear.

Thank you both for speedy replies

Comment: Is the second column ever `2` but not a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the Find Identical tool. Here's the steps I went through to accomplish it:

1. Run the Find Identical tool with your table as the input dataset with date/time chosen as the field of comparison. Check "Output only duplicated records".
2. Relate the output table IN_FID field to your original table OID field. Select all records in the output table and then choose your relate to select those records in the original table.
3. Select by attributes in your original table with "Select from current selection" as the method, then put "2ndColumn" = 2 in the WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "select by attributes" and build a query. Afterwards you just delete the ones selected.

```
"field1" = "field_duplicate" AND "field2" = 2
```

You can also negate with the != operator. ("field2" != 1) when you have more values in the field2.

Eventually you need to put the 2 in '2' when it is a text-field.

Answer (score 0):

A basic/non-sexy way is to create a new field that concatenates the two you're looking to identify by, and then create another field that looks for duplicates in your concatenated field. Select the newly identified and delete.